# Add Repository to GitHub Connection in ADS

Tags: github, azure-devops, github-api, ads-api

How to add GitHub repository to ADS (On-Prem) connection using API. Followed this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/github/connect-to-github?view=azure-devops) to establish connection between GitHub repos and ADS (GitHub connection). We can add repos manually, we are looking for APIs to add the repos.
[image]

Is there any API using which we can add GitHub repos to the GitHub connections in ADS?

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a documented REST API that can do this. But when I checked the Developer Console, I found that there is indeed a REST API that can add repository with existing GitHub connection:

```
POST https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/_apis/Contribution/HierarchyQuery?api-version=5.0-preview.1
```

Here is a sample request body:

```
{
    "contributionIds": [
        "ms.vss-work-web.github-unified-installation-experience-data-provider"
    ],
    "dataProviderContext": {
        "properties": {
            "orgName": "{organization}",
            "externalRepositoryExternalIds": [
                "{RepositoryExternalIds}",
                "{RepositoryExternalIds}"
            ],
            "existingConnectionId": "{ConnectionId}",
            "sourcePage": {
                "url": "https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_settings/boards-external-integration",
                "routeId": "ms.vss-admin-web.project-admin-hub-route",
                "routeValues": {
                    "project": "{project}",
                    "adminPivot": "boards-external-integration",
                    "controller": "ContributedPage",
                    "action": "Execute"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In the `externalRepositoryExternalIds` section, **note that you need to include all the repository ids you want, not just the new ones you want to add**.

**Other information that might help**: If you change the request body, the REST API will return all repositories that are currently connected. Here are some examples:

```
{
    "contributionIds": [
        "ms.vss-work-web.azure-boards-external-connection-data-provider"
    ],
    "dataProviderContext": {
        "properties": {
            "includeInvalidConnections": true,
            "sourcePage": {
                "url": "https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_settings/boards-external-integration",
                "routeId": "ms.vss-admin-web.project-admin-hub-route",
                "routeValues": {
                    "project": "{project}",
                    "adminPivot": "boards-external-integration",
                    "controller": "ContributedPage",
                    "action": "Execute",
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi  @Jane Ma-MSFT, Thank you for the API. Some confusion orgName do we need to provide GitHub org name without url? and also where can I find ConnectionId?